# Unable to add users to WSO2 user storage via SCIM REST API calls

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are planning to use WSO2 Identity Server as the identity provider for multiple websites and apps. Whenever a new member will register with our website, we will create a new user in WSO2 Identity Server which will then authenticate the users. I am planning to use SCIM REST APIs to create/update users in WSO2.

I was able to successfully retrieve the list of users from WSO2 by making GET request to this endpoint. So there is no issues with access permission.

```
https://identityserver:9443/wso2/scim/Users
```

But when I tried to add a new user (POST) I received the error below:

```
{
  "Errors": [
    {
      "description": "Error in adding the user: mj100@jackson.com to the user store. Cannot access the directory context or user already exists in the system for user :mj100@jackson.com",
      "code": "500"
    }
  ]
}
```

My request had a payload as below:

```
{
   "schemas":[
   ],
   "name":{
      "familyName":"Jackson",
      "givenName":"Michael"
   },
   "userName":"mj100@jackson.com",
   "password":"HiMike100",
   "emails":[
      {
         "primary":true,
         "value":"mj100@jackson.com",
         "type":"home"
      }
   ]
}
```

I received a similar error when I tried to update an user in WSO2 admin (carbon) portal:

```
Error while updating profile of abcd@test.com. Error is: One or more attributes you are trying to add/update are not supported by underlying LDAP for user : abcd@test.com
```

I am clueless on how to resolve this issue and why WSO2 will not allow me to update an user neither via console or via SCIM API.

I am using WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled using an email address as a username ?

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Using+Email+Address+as+the+Username

Comment: Not sure, the system was configured by an external consultant. But I can add user through admin console (carbon) with email as user name. But I cannot update that user.

Comment: Ok , then that should be enabled. Could you paste the error log entry in identityserver/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log when you try to do the SCIM call ?